# .net API Enable CORS for login

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an api application in .net. I've enabled cors via:
`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` and adding

```
    var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", 
                                       "Origin, Content-Type, Accept", 
                                       "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"); 
    config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);
```

to the `WebApiConfig.cs`
This works for the most part, and once I've enbled CORS on my controller with `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

I can make cross origin requests via get and post. However, I get the following error when trying to login via the default `/Token` endpoint. How can I enable CORS for this endpoint as I can't find the actual method.

```
Failed to load http://localhost:64501/token: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

The `/Token` endpoint is the default one that was scaffolded when you create a .net api application with authentication. I didn't create it.

The only reference to the `/Token` endpoint is in `Startup.Auth`

Here's the complete class

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //    consumerKey: "",
        //    consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //    appId: "",
        //    appSecret: "");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        //{
        //    ClientId = "",
        //    ClientSecret = ""
        //});
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't mention how you set the token endpoint up.

Comment: have added to the question

Comment: `The response had HTTP status code 400` Are you sure you're calling the correct endpoint?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I double checked

Comment: This isn't answerable without the code that sets up the token endpoint.  Not every project template is the same.  You need to provide that code, even if you didn't create it yourself.

Comment: I can't find it. The only reference to the endpoint in the project is `Startup.Auth` and I've added it to the question

Comment: Okay, good, and where is `OAuthOptions` used?  Is this Owin?  Please provide more than the bare minimum of code.  You (probably) need to add CORS to your Owin pipeline, but I can't yet make that determination.

Comment: Yes, it would be to add CORS to the Owin pipleline. I don't know where /Token maps to by default so I can't add cors to the method

Comment: @ColonelMustard, I'm with the same problem. Did you solve it?